# webcam inside web chat system

Tags: flash, video, webcam, live-streaming

I need to implement a webcam for a web chat system. Im trying to avoid that the video data goes through the webserver... it should go directly from client to client (as if they were using with skype).

Any ideas on where to start or what to use for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a google search for Flash P2P.

This looks like it might be a good starting point: [link text](http://www.derekentringer.com/blog/stratus-p2p-communication-using-rtmfp-and-flash-10/)